# How to find and store header line from list of files

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate over a list of files and store each file name along with the first header line from that file in a text document. I'm trying to do this with a for loop in a similar way as I've been able to do successfully for other commands. However, I'm getting the following error: -bash: =: command not found

Can anyone help solve this problem?

```
   for infile in *_L001.fastq;
    do
    info = gunzip -c ${infile} | head -1
    echo "${infile},$info"
    done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.

I had to output the relevant information using two separate commands since defining a variable in the loop was problematic. But using the -n tag to remove the default newline after the echo command and >> to append the output of each command to a text file worked. This resulted in a single line with each filename, followed by its header, in headers.txt.

```
for infile in _L001.fastq; 
    do echo -n $infile" " >> headers.txt
    gunzip -c $infile | head -1 >> headers.txt 
    done
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `>> headers.txt` inside the loop, it's a costly operation. It's better to redirect the output of the whole loop: `done >  headers.txt`